# Create input value find li id JQUERY

Tags: jquery

create code find input.val == li.id to hide li

```
var fi = $('#product_table').find('input').val();
$("#product_list ul li").filter(function(){
  $(this).hide($('li').attr(id).indexOf(fi) > -1)
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming a lot here... Since your question is real tiny on details.

This may put you on the right track anyway:

```js
$("#product_table").on("click",function(){
  var fi = $('#product_table').find('input:checked').val();
  
  $("#product_list ul li").hide();
  
  $("#product_list ul li").filter(function(){
    if($(this).attr("id")==fi){
      return $(this);
    }
  }).show()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="product_table">
  <input type="radio" name="test" value="1"> 1
  <input type="radio" name="test" value="2"> 2
  <input type="radio" name="test" value="3"> 3
</div>

<div id="product_list">
  <ul>
    <li id="1">One</li>
    <li id="2">Two</li>
    <li id="3">Three</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

As you can see... The [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-function) method can take a function as argument.... But this function has to return matching elements.

On the resulting collection, you can act, like show/hide them.